# How can we use passkit in frontend and stripe in the backend for apple pay implementation

Tags: stripe-payments, applepay, apple-appclips

I'm trying to integrate Apple Pay into the appclip of an iOS (SWIFTUI) app.
As I'm limited in size, I don't want to use Stripe in the front end because even the optimized version of Stripe Apple Pay SDK is 3–4 MB. I keep Appclip's size at a maximum of 10 MB. 
That's why I'm thinking of using Stripe in the backend. Is it possible?

Comment: Isn't the ApplePay module only 0.4MB ? https://docs.stripe.com/mobile/ios/sdk-23-migration?lang-ios=swift#modules 

https://docs.stripe.com/apple-pay?platform=ios#app-clips